# How to close IME Numeric keypad when done?

Tags: android, android-widget

My app has two EditText widgets.  Their inputtype is set to Number.  When I finish typing a number of the Numeric Keypad, I'd like them to disappear, but I have a NEXT button on the keypad, not a DONE button.  I had thought including this in the the XML would fix it, but it didn't work

```
android.imeOptions="actionDone"
```

I also tried putting this in the Java code, but it would not compile (cannot find symbol):

```
EditTextPrices.setImeOptions(actionDone);
```

Why won't that compile?  And, how can I get a DONE button instead of a NEXT button on my numeric keypads?

This is the full text of the EditText widget:

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextPrices"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android.imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

Comment: see docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions
https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I had thought including this in the the XML would fix it, but it didn't work

Namespaces in XML are delineated by a colon. Try `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`.

> Why won't that compile?

Because there nothing named `actionDone`. Use `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` instead of `actionDone`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your edittext.

```
android:imeActionLabel="Next"
```

Prasad EBIZ